# Serial communication stuck after first attempt

Tags: arduino

I am using arduino Mega 2560 to control some vibration motors with touchdesigner through Serial Communication. I maped the pixels to control each motors, It works for a few seconds and gets stuck very soon. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Here is my arduino sketch:

```
#define MOTOR_COUNT 12
int motors[MOTOR_COUNT];

void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Ready to receive frames.");

  for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
  }


void loop()
{
  
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    char c = Serial.peek();
    if (!(c >= '0' && c <= '9'))
    {
      Serial.read(); // Discard non-digit character
    }
    else if (Serial.read() == '\n')
    {
      for (uint16_t i = 0; i < MOTOR_COUNT; i++)
      {
        motors[i] = Serial.parseInt();
        Serial.print("motor ");
        Serial.print(i);
        Serial.print(":");
        Serial.println(motors[i]);

        if (i <= 12) {
          analogWrite(i + 2, motors[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. If you post example code it's appreciated if you keep it small and well-formatted. Posting dead code or lots of extra whitespace in your example is not very inviting for the reader :).

Comment: Hi , can u give error traces of when it does " get stuck" as u mentioend . Does it allso freeze when u do Serial.read() in isolation without the analogWrite() operation ?